# Static URL and CSS in Django

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles, django-static

I am trying to setup a static url in Django and have my templates use it to link to the css. Here is my code. Why is it not working? Also, what is the best practice for setting this up? Thanks.

```
# settings

import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    )


# urls

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of my URLconfs here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()


# html template

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" type="text/css">

# file structure
-project
--project
---settings
---static
----css
-----style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `STATICFILES_DIRS` needs to include a list of paths to your static directories for development. The `STATIC_ROOT` setting is used for collecting static files into a single directory in production to be served by HTTP server such as Nginx or Apache.

Seeing as you have already defined a `PROJECT_ROOT` you could do this:

```
# Assuming your settings.py is at the same level as your static directory
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'), ]
```

Comment: Still not working for me. Any more tips?

Comment: try [@catherine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15521262/1199394)'s answer too.

Comment: Ok something else must be wrong because even when I link it with the exact file path to the stylesheet it's not using the css, but I tested it on another file outside of django and it worked fine.